# Actuate 10 Information Object Designer with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, actuate

I cannot figure out how add a new Data Connection Definition in Actuate 10 Information Object Designer. The odbc is postgresql but when I input a Data Connection Definition Type, postgresql is not an option.
is this becuase Actuate 10 is too outdated? It is hard to find any infomration on this since most Actuate users use BIRT now.

Any information on the Actuate 10 Information Object Designer, or materials I could read would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to install the PostgreSQL ODBC driver.

One wrinkle there is that you might have a 64-bit system, and have installed the 64-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver. If Actuate is a 32-bit executable it won't see the 64-bit driver. You will need to install the 32-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver as well.

(The reverse is also true btw - 64-bit programs can't use the 32-bit driver either).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Acutally I am using Windows xp at work and I have the PostgreSQL ODBC installed, and it works for the Actuate Report Designer. I just cannnot get the Information Object Designer to work. I have the  PostgreSQL ANSI and PostgreSQL Unicode dirvers installed.

Comment: @user3224779 32-bit XP? (There is 64-bit XP, though it wasn't widely deployed). Maybe the problem tool has its own list of supported odbc drivers? Maybe it needs a DSN to exist, and can't just use the driver directly?